# how to get the peer list from torrent tracker response

Tags: bittorrent

I am making a torrent client. I decode the torrent file and send this request to the tracker:

```
http://tracker.mininova.org/announce?uploaded=0&downloaded=0&compact=0&event=started&peer_id=12345678987654321234&port=6881&info_hash=%18%28n%23K%ECt%B7%93S%C5%F1-%F3%1C%18k%CEX%A4&left=0
```

and this is what I received:

```
{'min interval': 1800, 'peers': '', 'interval': 1800, 'complete': 37, 'incomplete': 0}
```

Why is the peer list empty? There are 37 peers that are seeders, shouldn't I get some peer information from them?

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this question if you have figured it out. I used this example to implement my UDP , HTTP tracker response https://github.com/erindru/m2t/blob/58c34f97a5ae613e98cf63e562a4de63e936a071/m2t/scraper.py

Comment: Bit late I guess. Did you try setting compact=1 in your query string. Some trackers only support compact peers list. See https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_Request_Parameters

Answer (score 4):

The reason that you got an empty peer list is because the tracker don't send seeds to other seeds and there was no leechers registered at the moment of the request.

The tracker registered you as a seed because you sent `&left=0`in the request string, indicating that you have the complete torrent.

Instead, say the torrent is 200075 bytes and the client has not downloaded anything yet,
it should add `&left=200075`and the announce will be:

```
http://tracker.mininova.org/announce?uploaded=0&downloaded=0&compact=0&event=started&peer_id=12345678987654321234&port=6881&info_hash=%18%28n%23K%ECt%B7%93S%C5%F1-%F3%1C%18k%CEX%A4&left=200075
```

and there will be no answer because the tracker is long dead.

See: https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrent_Tracker_Protocol#Basic_Tracker_Announce_Request

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the trackers you're querying just aren't storing peers for that torrent. I was able to find peers using DHT.

The URL would be magnet:?xt=urn:btih:18286e234bec74b79353c5f12df31c186bce58a4 .