# Get IP addresses from udp and http torrent tracker response

Tags: python, scrape, bittorrent, tracker

I am trying to get the peer-list: list of IP addresses from a torrent tracker

Similar to the question here: [how to get the peer list from torrent tracker response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750775/how-to-get-the-peer-list-from-torrent-tracker-response)

I wrote code which decodes the torrent files using the python [bencode Bit-torrent library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BitTorrent-bencode) 
I wrote code following this code [here](https://github.com/erindru/m2t/blob/58c34f97a5ae613e98cf63e562a4de63e936a071/m2t/scraper.py) to scrape torrent tracker.

At least for http request like to mininova tracker I get the following output for a specific info_hash

```
{'files': {'\xbf\xff&\xcdY\x05\x9b\xb2C2j\x83\xf5F_\x9bg\x9d\xe2G': {'downloaded': 25416, 'complete': 12, 'incomplete': 0}}}
```

I do not see any of the other keys that the BitTorrent documents [here](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification) in the spec. (like tracker_id, min_interval, peers ...etc)

How can I get the peer list?

Answer (score 2):

Not all torrents send you a peer list for scrape requests, in fact what I found is that barely any of the big ones do. You need to send them a request that you started downloading the torrent (at the announce URL), only then will you get a peer list. You can look at the binary data yourself to see if peers are there or not or you could upload a sample response for me.

Answer (score 2):

To get a peer list etc. from the tracker, you need to make an `announce` to it.
What you ar doing is a `scrape`.

You can find an example of an `announce` here: [Why does tracker server NOT understand my request? (Bittorrent protocol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418004/why-does-tracker-server-not-understand-my-request-bittorrent-protocol/24001128#24001128)

More info about `scrape` here: http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Scrape
[Decode Torrent Hash of Torrent tracker scrape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23866922/decode-torrent-hash-of-torrent-tracker-scrape/23976974#23976974)